# How to Scroll to "Watches sections" Appium

Tags: java, appium

My scroll here is scrolling all the way to bottom.

But  I need to scroll down to "Watches section",which I am not able to perform.

```
    loginpage.getMensFashionList().click();//clicks on Mens Fashion
    //Scroll to watches section.
    driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textMatches(\"Watches\").instance(0))");
```

After clicking on mens' fashion, I need to scroll to watches section as I am intrested in watches.

Below is the image of watches section:
[image]

need help to scroll only till watches section.

[image: UI automator]

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"your scrollable list id\")).scrollIntoView("
                + "new UiSelector().textContains(\"Watches\").instance(1))"));
```

Comment: can you please help me where I can find scroll able resource id,I am new to appium ,please help

Comment: you can see it in uiautomatorviewer top right section where you can find list of elements,

Comment: currently resource id is blank..attached screenshot of uiautomator in description..please check and help me in this regards

Comment: I tried with this below code:driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping:id/mash_web_fragment\")).scrollIntoView("
                + "new UiSelector().textContains(\"Watches \").instance(1))"));
But it didnt work

Comment: @SubanDhyako How would you handle if there are multiple scrolls and instance(0) and instance(1) is dynamically changed